# Webmatrix Login not working

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix, razor-2

this is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add
 name="SQLServerConnectionString"
 connectionString= "server=localhost;database=NAPH_Local;trusted_connection=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is my _AppStart.cshtml

```
@{
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("SQLServerConnectionString", "UserProfile",         "UserId", "Email",  autoCreateTables: true);
 }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>        
</body>
</html>
```

this is my registration page

```
@{
 Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";

// Initialize page
var email = "";
var password = "";
var confirmPassword = "";
var ErrorMessage = "";

// If this is a POST request, validate and process data
if (IsPost)
{
email = Request.Form["Email"];
password = Request.Form["Password"];
confirmPassword = Request.Form["ConfirmPassword"];

if (email.IsEmpty() || password.IsEmpty()) 
{ErrorMessage = "You must specify both email and password.";}

if (password != confirmPassword)
{ErrorMessage = "Password and confirmation do not match.";}

// If all information is valid, create a new account
if (ErrorMessage=="")
{ 
var db = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString");
var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) =       LOWER(@0)", email);
if (user == null)
  {
  db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email) VALUES (@0)", email);
  WebSecurity.CreateAccount(email, password, true);
  // Navigate back to the homepage and exit
  Response.Redirect("Login.cshtml");
  }
  else
  {ErrorMessage = "Email address is already in use.";}
}
}

if (ErrorMessage!="")
{
<p>@ErrorMessage</p> 
<p>Please correct the errors and try again.</p>
}

}

<h1>Register</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
<legend>Sign-up Form</legend>
<ol>
<li>
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" value="@Request.Form["Email"]" />
</li>
<li>
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="@Request.Form["Password"]" />
</li>
<li>
<label>Confirm Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" />
</li>
<li>
<p><input type="submit" value="Register" /></p>
</li>
</ol>
</fieldset>
```

Login Page code

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";

var email = "";
var password = "";
var ErrorMessage = "";

// If this is a POST request, validate and process data
if (IsPost)
  {
  email = Request.Form["email"];
  password = Request.Form["password"];
  if (email.IsEmpty() || password.IsEmpty())
    {ErrorMessage = "You must specify a username and password.";}  
  else
  {
  // Login, Navigate back to the homepage and exit
  if (WebSecurity.Login(email, password, true))
    {Response.Redirect("@Exercise.cshtml");}
    else
    {ErrorMessage = "Login failed, check your credentials";}
  }
}

if (ErrorMessage!="") 
{
<p>@ErrorMessage</p> 
<p>Please correct the errors and try again.</p>
}

}

<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
<legend>Log In to Your Account</legend>
<ol>
<li>
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text"  name="email" value="@Request.Form["Email"]" />
</li>
<li>
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password"  name="password" value="@Request.Form["Password"]"  />
</li>
<li>
<p><input type="submit" value="login" /></p>
</li>
</ol>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I am using SQL Server 2012. I wants create a simple login, so that user can register and login to enter data.

this is the error i am getting when i tried to register with email and password. Please excuse me, i am new to web development world.

Many thanks in advance

---

Regards
Abu

Comment: What is the error message that you receive?

Comment: Hi, Certainly i have managed to solve the registration page issue. i could register but can't login, page do not proceed further. i have added login page code above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to web development, maybe your best option should be to follow a tutorial that explains WebSecurity functionalities, as [Adding Security and Membership to an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership).
It doesn't make use of Sql Server 2012, but this could be your next step.

The reason of your login problems could be the WebSecurity initialization. The `InitializeDatabaseConnection` method in your `_AppStart.cshtml` file has the `autoCreateTables` parameter set to `false`. This premises that in your database you have already created webpages_Membership, webpages_OAuthMembership, webpages_Roles and webpages_UsersInRoles tables. If this tables don't exist you must set the parameter to `true`, so `InitializeDatabaseConnection` sets up them for you.

Comment: Hi, I did set autoCreateTable to true and indeed it has created those table. I am able to Register for the new users and i could see in the database table that user has been created but won't be able log in at all. I am following all the steps according to the book as well without luck.

Comment: I have updated my login code above. Thanks in advanced